# Type 'interrupt' attribute only applies to functions [-Wattributes] when using typedef function pointer

Tags: pointers, gcc, attributes, warnings, interrupt

I have the following line of code:

```
typedef void(* foo)(void) __attribute__ ((interrupt));
```

When using LPCXpresso to compile the project I get a compiler warning:

```
Type 'interrupt' attribute only applies to functions [-Wattributes]
```

Could anyone give me a hint on how to fix this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is a little bit picky about whose attribute is. Just apply it explicitly to function type, rather then to typedef declaration itself:

```
typedef void(* __attribute__ ((interrupt)) foo)(void);
```

I just tested this on ARM compiler.